# If $\lambda$ is a symmetric measure, can we show $\int_{\overline B_1(0)}\lambda({\rm d}x)x=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(E)$ of a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space $E$ and $$\lambda^-(B):=\lambda(-B)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B(E).$$

> Assuming $\lambda=\lambda^-$, how can we show that $$x(\lambda):=-\int_{\overline B_1(0)}\lambda({\rm d}x)x=0?\tag1$$

I'm pretty sure that this isn't hard to show, but I for the moment I have no idea how we obtain $(1)$. Maybe we can show the stronger result that $\lambda(B)=0$ for all $B\in\mathcal B(E)$ which are "symmetric" (i.e. $-B=B$). If we could show this, then $$\left\|x(\lambda)\right\|\le\lambda\left(\overline B_1(0)\right)=0\tag2.$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure the stronger result "$\lambda(B)=0$ for symmetric $B$" need not hold. The uniform distribution on $[-1, 1]$ satisfies $\lambda = \lambda^{-}$ but not $\lambda([-1, 1])=0$.

Comment: Is $\int_A \lambda(\mathrm dx)x$ a weird notation for $\int_A x\,\mathrm d \lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_A x \ \lambda(dx) = \int_A x \ \lambda^{-}(dx) = \int_{-A} (-x) \lambda(dx)$$
where the first equality is due to $\lambda=\lambda^{-}$, and the second is a change of variables.

If $A=-A$, then the final integral equals $-\int_A x \ \lambda(dx)$, which concludes the proof.